# How do I get number of combination for pairs of football teams?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Suppose we have 8 football teams playing each other in 4 matches. How do I find the number of combinations that is possible?

E.g. Teams A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H can be in the following matches:
Match 1: A vs C

Match 2: B vs G

Match 3: D vs H

Match 4: E vs F

This is one possible combination.
And how can I generalise this result to N football teams in N/2 matches?

Comment: Are (as the example sort of indicates) the matches *labelled*?

Comment: In addition, is A v B different to B v A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\binom{8}{2}$ choices for Match 1, $\binom{6}{2}$ choices for Match 2, $\binom{4}{2}$ choices for Match 3, and $\binom{2}{2}$ choices for Match 4. So for 8 teams, there are 
$$
\binom{8}{2}\times\binom{6}{2}\times
\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{2}{2}
$$
possibilities. Can you generalize this?